# MySQL Trigger which compares all OLD and NEW for changes need to be simplified

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want my "audit" triggers to be simpler to maintain.
Actually, on a Before update trigger, the logic is as follows :

```
IF NEW.field <> OLD.field THEN INSERT INTO table SET field=OLD.field
```

I am checking every column for changes because I don't want to store rows which are not really updated. There are many monitored columns and when I change a table (adding or deleting a column), I have to edit the triggers to reflect the new table structure.

Is there a simple way of going through each colum like this :

```
FOR EACH COL BEGIN IF NEW.COL <> OLD.COL THEN SET changedetected=true; END IF; END
```

And after that, using a FOR loop the same way to populate the Audit table with all the table's columns ?

I don't know if I am being clear enough, please post comments if needed.

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of columns from

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

then you can just wrap the query into a [`CURSOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) and loop through the names.

For comparison itself, I suppose you could [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) a statement for it

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT OLD.', col_name, ' = NEW.', col_name, ' INTO @cmp');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
IF @cmp ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use prepared statements in MySQL triggers.